# How to create drop shadow for back button of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back-button, dropshadow

I created a translucent navigation bar and set the tint color of it to white. However, there's a specific VC containing a map and a white back button on the map is not quite visible sometimes.

Therefore, I created a back button image with shadow and use `navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage` to set it in `viewWillAppear` of that VC and set back the normal image when the VC is not on top of the stack through

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

of the previous VC. That works fine.

However, when I test to span **halfway back** from the map VC to the previous VC but then release the spanning so that the map VC does not get dismissed but still triggers `viewWillAppear` of the previous VC, at this time the `backIndicatorImage` is set to normal image, which I do not expect.

How could I achieve the goal? Or is there any way to set the drop shadow on the back button of `UINavigationBar` for only a specific VC in `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationControllerDelegate` has a method called `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` which you could use to animate alongside the navigation controller push/pop animation.

In short, you should subclass `UINavigationController` and make it a delegate of itself:

```
import UIKit

class AppNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension AppNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard animated, let vc = viewController as? ShadowBackButtonProtocol, vc.shouldAddShadowToImage, let image = vc.myImage else {
            return
        }

        navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            if vc.shouldAddShadowToImage {
                // Add your shadow
            } else {
                // Remove the shadow
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Of course, both view controllers should have to implement `ShadowBackButtonImage`:

```
protocol ShadowBackImageButton {
    var shouldAddShadowToImage: Bool { get }
    var myImage: UIImage? { get }
}

extension MyViewController: ShadowBackImageButton {
    var shouldAddShadowToImage: Bool { return true }
    var myImage: UIImage? { return navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage }
}

extension AnotherSubclassOfViewController: ShadowBackImageButton {
    var shouldAddShadowToImage: Bool { return false }
    var myImage: UIImage? { return navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage }
}
```

If you ask me, I would prefer to add a `UIView` over the view controller that has to add a shadow and simply mimick the `UINavigationBar` appearance, as `navigationController(_:willShow:animated)` has had some issues when performing the **back** animation (that is probably a bug).

Comment: I finally end up accepting the bug as it's a rare case. Implement separate buttons and simulate the nav bar seems to be good as well but I don't have enough time for it. Thank you! Alejandro!

Comment: Yes. The main difference with your initial approach is `animate(alongsideTransition:)`. You could, for example, change the `alpha` of the shadow color instead of replacing the image, using a `navigationFinalAlpha` in each `UIViewController` and animating the color to `vc.navigationFinalAlpha`, where `vc` is the destination view controller. The problem doesn't occur when you're dragging using your finger, it appears when you press the **back** button, it simply won't change until the transition has ended (and that's the probable bug I was talking about). Anyway, it -kinda- works.